# pre middleware in all mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wonder, is there any way to set a `pre` middleware for all schemas (tables) in mongoose ?!

I want to track all activities and save a log for all changes and creations in the database.

Maybe something like this..

```
Mongoose.schemas.pre('save', () => {...} );
```